# Maven reactor and site

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin, maven-reactor

I have a multi-module project with a parent `pom.xml` and several modules where some of the modules depend on each other. In the project directory I can call

```
mvn test
```

to run unittests in each module. No problem here. But if I call

```
mvn site
```

one of the modules reports

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myModule_C: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project org.myModule_C:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be
resolved: org.myModule_A:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, org.myModule_B:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure
to find org.myModule_A:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://artifactory-server:8081/artifactory/repo
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
interval of server has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I think this should not happen since these dependencies are found during "mvn test". Also, they are not in the artifactory-server but part of the parent project. The goal that is mentioned in the ERROR is the goal `site`. Why does the `mvn test` succeed (with respect to dependencies it finds) and `mvn site` does not? Do I have to build the site in a special way - because this is a reactor build?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007005/maven-site-on-multi-module-project-could-not-resolve-dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute the `mvn install` as least once. Please see further information at the [Maven Build Life Cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

Here is the overview

#### Maven Phases

Although hardly a comprehensive list, these are the most common default lifecycle phases executed.

`validate`: validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available

`compile`: compile the source code of the project

`test`: test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed

`package`: take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.

`integration-test`: process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run

`verify`: run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria

`install`: install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally

`deploy`: done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

##### There are two other Maven lifecycles of note beyond the default list above

They are:

`clean`: cleans up artifacts created by prior builds

`site`: generates site documentation for this project

I hope this may help.

Comment: When focusing on reactor-build i have in mind the quote from the "Guide to Working with Multiple Modules" - "This part of the maven core does the following: 1) Collects all the available modules 2) Sorts the projects into the correct build order 3) Builds the selected projects in order". A bit suprising that this does not work for site's.

Comment: The site also does the same way as well. You may see further information at site:stage

Comment: Doing a maven install pollutes my local repository when all I want to do is generate a site for the current snapshot source tree. For most plugins, combining the plugin with the package lifecycle (e.g. mvn package dependency:tree) does the trick. Not so for site. I'm tempted to call it a bug.